# Java Date format issue?

Tags: java, jodatime, isodate

I have a String date:

```
2013-05-23T00:00:00+00:00
```

And I want to format it using the `ISODateTimeFormat` class:

```
DateTimeFormatter myParser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
myDate = myParser.parseDateTime(myDateAsString).toDate();
```

The formatted date value is :

```
Thu May 23 01:00:00 BST 2013
```

Where is that 1 hour coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Your `DateTimeFormatter` is using the local time zone. You need to create a formatter that uses the UTC time zone, like so:

```
DateTimeFormatter myParser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withZoneUTC();
```

Comment: that still returns the same datetime : Thu May 23 01:00:00 BST 2013

Comment: You don't show the code that you're using to format the date, only to parse. How are you formatting it?

Comment: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); return df.format(date); the problem occurs if I have a date that has a time that is in the last hour of the day, i.e. 2013-05-23T23:59:59+00:00 because this creates a date object with an incorrect date when I use the date format, i.e. 2013-05-24

Answer (score 1):

Notice the time zone offset, it has the BST offset which is +1 against the GMT. It is probably related to the time zone you are in. However, the BST ended 4 days ago.

One remark, why not use ISO8601 time format? I personally find it more managable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601